# Best Way to Fill 3D Scatter Points? (MatPlotLib, Py 3.10)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following `Python 3.10` script to generate a simple 3D Scatter Plot with `MatPlotLib`, according to the [MatPlotLib 3D Scatter tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

X = [1, 3, 2]
Y = [1, 1, 2]
Z = [2, 2, 2]

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlim(0, 4)
ax.set_ylim(0, 3)
ax.set_zlim(1.9, 2.1)

ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Axis')

plt.show()
```

The script above works as intended, and I get the correct output:

[image]

However, I was wondering whether it would be possible to connect & fill the scatter points, to create a "face" of sorts, and to provide a color for it.
In this case, it would be as such:

[image]

I looked around the other `MatPlotLib` tutorials, notably the ones for the [3D Surface Colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html) plot and the [3D Surface Solid Color](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_2.html) plot, however it's confusing to me how they are implemented.

From what I could gather by attempting to run the examples, the Z-axis data set is a multi-dimensional array (the interperter threw up an error if I simply supplied a singular list or np array to it). I don't really understand why the Z-axis data set needs to be a multi-dimensional array, as I would imagine that the actual data colors are supplied via the `color` argument to the `scatter` function call.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with `MatPlotLib`? Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is [`plot_trisurf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

X = [1, 3, 2]
Y = [1, 1, 2]
Z = [2, 2, 2]

ax.scatter3D(X, Y, Z)
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

[image: surface plot]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. However, is it possible to supply it with a list of colors to use, instead of just a singular color for all faces? So I can get generated faces with different colors?

Comment: Yes, this is the `color` argument, just check the documentation on the link I provided.

Comment: Well, if I provide it with a list of lists, one list for each generated face, I get an error... Do you know of a way to provide a different color for each generated face? Or do they all have to strichtly have to be the same color? I also saw on the documentation, that the "cmap" argument can be provided, but it apparently can only supply pre-defined color patterns. Is it possible to generate a custom one?

Comment: I'm not sure how you do that, as it is specified in the documentation that `X`, `Y` and `Z` arguments must be "Data values as 1D arrays". I get an error when I try what you say. But basically, just do a for loop.

Comment: For colormaps there is some documentation there: ["Creating a colormap from a list of colors"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/custom_cmap.html), ["Creating Colormaps in Matplotlib"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html)